# Haskell "(.|.)" syntax

Tags: haskell

What does this syntax mean? (in the context of module declaration)

Example:

```
module XMonad (
    module XMonad.Main,
    module XMonad.Core,
    module XMonad.Config,
    module XMonad.Layout,
    module XMonad.ManageHook,
    module XMonad.Operations,
    module Graphics.X11,
    module Graphics.X11.Xlib.Extras,
    (.|.),
    MonadState(..), gets, modify,
    MonadReader(..), asks,
    MonadIO(..)
) where
```

Can't find anything using search engines.

Comment: `(.|.)` is the name of an operator defined in the module you're looking at.

Comment: [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is a great resource for searching for these kinds of answers.

Comment: @DavidYoung Slight correction: `(.|.)` is the name of an operator that is in scope in the module you're looking at. Might be defined elsewhere -- Haskell allows you to re-export things (and I'm pretty sure this is an example of that happening).

Comment: @DanielWagner That is a good point. I just assumed that wasn't the case because of the module exports before it but that could certainly be what is happening (for a more "fine grained" export).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "Bitwise or". It is an operator that the XMonad package re-exports. It is originally defined in [Data.Bits](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html).

> https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.13/docs/XMonad.html#v:.-124-.

```
(.|.) :: Bits a => a -> a -> a #

    Bitwise "or"
```

In Haskell, anything defined between `(` ... `)` is an operator, which is a function that works by default as infix notation.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks! I thought it's some syntax sugar.

Comment: @Siegmeyer almost all “syntax” in Haskell is really just a library function in infix form. You can [use Hayoo](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=.%7C.) to search for them.

Comment: Naturally, there's also [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) as a Hayoo alternative.